# reinitialize ajax-loaded processing.js sketch

Tags: javascript, jquery, processing.js

I know there is an automatic initialization method used to start sketches on conventional websites. Is there a way to reactivate on pageload? I know where to put the code, but I don't see the function to call to start the sketch. I've already tried `processing.init();` although it doesn't look like it is stored as a function outright... Thanks for your help! I asked a similar question earlier, but it was the a libraries own function that fixed it, not the jquery `.on()`, `live()`, `delegate()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We're adding that for the next version, actually, where it will be called Processing.reload()

In the mean time you can manually create new Processing instances, either by using new Processing(...) or Processing.loadSketchFromSources(...)